# Mypy import not typing correctly

Tags: mypy

I have a type, Flag, in `stubs/my_types/__init__.py`

```
__all__ = ["Flag"]
Flag = TypedDict(
    'Flag', {
        'id': int
    })
```

In my main source program, I import this with

```
from stubs.my_types import Flag
```

have a function I have annotated with

```
def do_stuff(thing: int) -> List[Flag]:
```

I've set the MYPYPATH to where the main source program is, but VsCode still shows the `Flag` as type `Any`. How can I get it to show the correct type?

Comment: Did you make sure to import TypedDict from the `mypy_extensions` module? (Make sure to pip-install the module first though).

Comment: Yeah I've given up on it for now.